# SQLite: the database is locked

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, database-connection, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using flask with sqlalchemy and sqlite db. I have 2 ajax that send some data from html to my .py file.

The problem is every time when i do any of these 2 operations, the second one become unavailable because of lock of db. Also, if first chosen action will be deleting, then exception firing no matter what operation will be chosen after. with first choice of adding, we can add without limitations that's strange too, because functions seem similar.

I've tried timeouts, closing sessions in a different ways, the result is always the same.

Here are two functions-handlers:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
csrf = CSRFProtect(app)

app.config.from_object('config')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

import forms
import models


@app.route('/delete', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def delete():
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.form['type'] == "delete":
            print("delete")
            engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI)
            Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
            session = Session()

            try:
                print("try")
                requested = request.form['id']
                print(requested)
                models.Income.query.filter(models.Income.id == requested).delete()
                session.commit()
            except:
                print("rollback")
                session.rollback()
            finally:
                print("fin")
                session.close()

            ellist = models.Income.query.all()
            return render_template("incomeSection.html", list=ellist)


@app.route('/add', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add():
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.form['type'] == "add":
            print('add')
            engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI)
            Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
            session = Session()

            try:
                print("try")
                newItem = models.Income(name=request.form['name'], tag=request.form['tag'],
                                        account=request.form['account'],
                                        date=date(*(int(i) for i in request.form['date'].split("-"))))
                session.add(newItem)
                session.commit()
            except:
                print('rollback')
                session.rollback()
            finally:
                print("fin")
                session.close()

            ellist = models.Income.query.all()
            print(ellist)
            return render_template("incomeSection.html", list=ellist)
```

I've read that this exception caused by non-closed connections, but I have .close() in every finally block. I think the problem might be because of the `db = SQLAlchemy(app)` but I don't know how to fix if that is the case. Because I use this variable to connect with db in forms.py where I have the form template and in models.py where I defined my tables within db.

Answer (score 0):

So, aperrently, thete was an issue with number of connections.
The thing that solved my problem was the context manager for sqlalchemy, i used this one:

```
class SQLAlchemyDBConnection(object):

def __init__(self, connection_string):
    self.connection_string = connection_string
    self.session = None

def __enter__(self):
    engine = create_engine(self.connection_string)
    Session = sessionmaker()
    self.session = Session(bind=engine)
    return self

def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
    self.session.commit()
    self.session.close()
```

and in the handler just

```
with SQLAlchemyDBConnection(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI) as db:
            newItem = models.Income(*your params*)
            db.session.add(newItem)
```

And now it works fine, but i still don't know what was the issue in version that was earlier. They are seem to be same just with or without context manager